# Why did the Community user reject my suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, community-user, rejected-edits

I have recently edited a question in which I added the code blocks for the entire question. Another user approved the edit however, Community came along and rejected the edit.

[image]

Is it because adding code blocks is not necessary for questions? Or should Community need tweaking?

Comment: It probably collided with another edit made at the same time possibly by the OP, in which case the Community user takes the blame for the rejection.

Comment: No, the Community user is assigned to rejections that cannot directly be attributed to another user. The post was most likely edited by someone else after the suggested edit was submitted (because they already had the editor open).

Comment: A corresponding message would be appropriate so as not to confuse users into asking suck questions as this.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Your [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4599028) was **automatically** rejected, because another, later edit conflicted with it.

Since the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133880/how-to-get-a-inputrichtext-values) has no revision history yet, that means the post was edited in the 5 minute grace period by the original owner.

You could make the same suggestion again; the post still looks a mess and could do with cleaning up!

Community is assigned the rejection because the system requires that a user id is assigned to all suggested edit vote records. Community does not reject suggested edits because of the contents; that is what we have a voting system for.