# Edit ban because of Community rejections

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, community-user, edit-ban

Whenever I edit a post, a warning shows up:

> Attention! Some of your previous edits were rejected. While reasonable edits may be rejected for many reasons outside of your control, you should review your recently-rejected edits before continuing.

I'm close to 2k reputation anyway, so I don't think it will really affect me much.

However, do edit bans take into account that most of my recently rejected edits were rejected by [Community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250129/why-did-the-community-user-reject-my-suggested-edit), specifically, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6318113), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6308173), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6308173), and  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6297369) (okay, I admit the last one wasn't the best edit ever, because I ignored obvious issues like "fallow")?

Am I actually in danger of being edit banned? If not, this message should not come up when most edit rejections are by community. If so, is there anything I (or, since I'm close to 2k anyway, users in general) can do to stop this risk?

I have read the question [Why did the Community user reject my suggested edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250129/why-did-the-community-user-reject-my-suggested-edit) but it did not address edit bans.

Comment: @cVplZ: I don’t see how that question addresses edit bans due to a Community rejection.

Comment: Reject and Edit counts toward the ban, @raff. I'll write a full answer when I'm not using a phone to post.

Comment: Community rejects post *by proxy* when *Reject and Edit* is used. I'd expect that to count for a ban.

Comment: @Shog9 Could you please update the old answer (linked above your comment)?

Comment: @Shog9: presumably that changed then, because Emmet stated that they *don't* since it is just the one user triggering the veto.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, @MartijnPieters - I've updated Emmett's answer and provided some additional details on what changed and why in [my own answer here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277893/edit-ban-because-of-community-rejections/277928#277928).

Comment: @Shog9: yup, saw the change, and updated my answer to link to the updated info. Thanks!

Comment: @Teemu: who says this user has made any bad edits? They had **one** suggested edit rejected in the past month, by the author of the edited post, because that author apparently didn't like the bracket style used.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are (at least) two *different* reasons why Community User is blamed for an suggested edit rejection:

- The edit conflicted; someone else *also* edited the post, but their edit applied directly. This usually happens when both you and someone with 2k+ reputation opened the post editor around the same time. A suggested edit is rejected automatically in that case.
- The edit was explicitly rejected by a reviewer, but they chose to edit the post at the same time. The review queue offers a *Reject and Edit* option for this. Because editing the post requires that the suggested edit is first rejected *out right*, Community User rejects the post because that counts as a veto vote (i.e. the reviewer doesn't have to wait until the post has gained 3 rejection votes).

Automatic rejections due to an editing conflict [do not count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137611/suggested-edit-rejections-for-concurrent-edits-should-not-count-for-the-suggeste/182983#182983). Rejections because a *reviewer* used the *Reject and Edit* button [**do** count towards a ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182983).

Of the sample rejected edit suggestions, only one counted against you; 3 are listed as:

> This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.

and do not count against a ban. One was listed as:

> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.

because the author of the post used *Reject and Edit* to make a *different* edit, and it does count towards a ban. My guess is that they wanted a different indentation style, but why their own version is any better is not immediately obvious to me.

I looked at all your edit suggestions made in the past 30 days, and that is the **only** rejection that'd count towards a ban. You are nowhere near a ban, and don't need to worry.

The warning may seem a little premature here, but perhaps you can review why so many of your suggested edits conflicted; perhaps you were trying to edit posts that were almost guaranteed to be edited because they were *just* posted.

Comment: Surely this means that the warning message should be re-programmed so that it only shows when an edit rejection *does* count towards a ban?

Comment: @cybermonkey: does it matter that much? And I didn't check further than 30 days, but it could be the warning is shown for rejections over a larger time span. Or even for just one rejection.

Comment: Good point. Besides if users think they are receiving the message in error, they can simply ignore it; a few accepted edits should be enough to hide it.

Comment: _`"Because editing the post requires that the suggested edit is first rejected out right"`_ - no, just copy the post id to stackoverflow.com/posts/<id>/edit and the editor pops up, no matter if there is a suggested edit pending or not

Comment: @msrd0: I'm talking about the review queue here. And going to the post revisions and choosing `edit` there will cause an edit conflict and thus a rejection by Community User for the suggested edit. It just doesn't count as a review rejection in that case, which may not be what you want.

Comment: For what it's worth, the one outright rejection was by the OP (1 rep), and his alternative looks worse.

Comment: @Deduplicator: yeah, I'm not sure why they felt the need to reject then further bodge up their indentation there.

Comment: `I looked at all your edit suggestions made in the past 30 days`.... THAT is what makes this an amazing community and you an amazing part of it.

Answer (score 19):

A bit of background information to complement Martijn's answer, since a lot of the details behind this are scattered across the meta sites:

Until recently, the edit-ban system completely ignored rejections by [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community); since edit conflicts could trigger such rejections, using those made it extremely likely that folks editing new posts would be [banned for no fault of their own](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137611/suggested-edit-rejections-for-concurrent-edits-should-not-count-for-the-suggeste).

This presented a problem for implementing [warnings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor/137334#137334), however: the warning criteria has to be evaluated every time someone opens the editor, and pulling in the data needed to exclude Community's rejections made that unacceptably slow. This actually ended up blocking implementation of the very-popular warning feature for a long time, but eventually we got around it by recording the *reason* for the rejection with the edit itself and simply excluding edits rejected for that reason.

That change was followed by [a revamp for how the "Improve" feature worked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor/238039#238039) for rejections. Now instead of rejecting edits while applying them to the post anyway, it completely discards the edit in favor of one the reviewer submits themselves - a behavior much closer to that of edit conflicts, but with the notable difference that this rejection is *intentional* on the part of the editor. Given this distinction (and the fact that we can now trivially differentiate between the two scenarios), it made sense to have these rejections count towards warnings and bans, while still excluding the unintended "conflict" rejections.

Note that the warning you received is triggered by the presence of [at least *one* rejected edit in the past week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor/137334#137334); the goal is simply to encourage you to review your past edits, not alert you to a looming ban - there's a more severe message reserved for *that*.

Comment: Right, I was [researching the warnings](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137334) and it wasn't clear to me that just the one rejection in the past week could trigger the issue.