# Are conflicting edits correctly ignored for reject count?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits, statistics

I saw on the editor's stats of [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6395961) that I had 3 previous rejected edit suggestions and went to my activity page to see which one were rejected and try to improve myself.

Two of them were rejected because they conflicted with an other edit. According to [this answer on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277893/edit-ban-because-of-community-rejections/277900#277900), those do not count for automatic ban. But they still count in the accepted/rejected stats shown for the editor.  I know this count shouldn't influence reviewers (I personally look at it only *after* completing my review if I'm curious), but I feel like it deforms the editor's credibility a bit when people do look at it.

Should this type of rejected suggestion count in the stats?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318423/suggested-edits-being-rejected-due-to-worse-conflicting-edits