# Suggested edits being rejected due to worse conflicting edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

A similar question [has been asked before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295164/edits-rejected-because-they-conflict-with-a-subsequent-edit-shouldnt-count-as-a), but with, as explained in the answer, different circumstances.

I made an edit suggestion, which, at least in my mind, was completely reasonable. It was rejected due to a conflict. This happens from time to time. However in this case the conflicting edit is addressing essentially the same issues, but doing so arguably worse - It has *(arguably)* worse formatting, corrects fewer English errors, and leaves in the "fluff".

The worst part is that this was not done by the original poster who may be unfamiliar with site rules and etiquette, but by a long time high-rep user, who should really know better. His edit resulted in:

- An *(arguably)* worse state of the answer than if he had simply done nothing at all.
- A bad record in my editing stats, which has nothing to do with the quality of my edit.

I would have reported it, but it seems as of now there is no way to report edits. *(Should there be?)* What should be done in this particular case? What should I do if this happens again? Shouldn't there be some measures which prevent this from happening in the first place?

My rejected edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11526467

His edit (revision 2): https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35828325/revisions

Here is another example, this one was even approved by 2 users before being rejected by a conflict: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11533196

Comment: Its worth noting that rejected edits due to conflicting subsequent ones do not count against you in edit-limit heuristics or automatic flags.

Comment: I suppose I do not understand the editing logic well enough, but I would have thought he wouldn't be able to submit his edit as long as your was pending (unless he hit "Reject and Edit" on your edit, but then that wouldn't have been a conflict).

Comment: @CodyGray If another editor already has the window to edit open, and then submits their edit after one has been suggested, the suggested edit gets rejected by the community user with that reason.

Comment: @CodyGray in addition to Magisch's reason, the edit URL can also be directly entered into the address bar to get to the edit window.  It will behave the same way as if the user had the edit window open

Comment: ..And in addition the mobile apps will always let you edit, which will autoreject the pending suggested edit.

Comment: @Magisch They may have the window open, but as soon as another edit is made a big orange warning appears notifying about the other edit. Any sensible person would think *"Hm, maybe I should pay attention to the bigass orange warning on my screen?"*

Comment: @psub Sounds like a bug to me. And Jonas's observation, too. If you do that and there is a pending edit, it should force you to deal with it. I used to hate that, but now that we have both "Approve and Edit" and "Reject and Edit," I think *all* pending edits should be blocking, no excuses.

Comment: The described problem and the big orange warning happen to me on a regular basis. The way I understand the warning is that the edit that makes the most changes is the one that "wins". I've never done it, but I suppose I could copy the entire content of the editing box to a text editor, submit my edit and, if it loses, open the question once more for editing. If on comparing I find the other edit poorer I could replace it with mine, or fix up what the other edit missed based on my previous work...

Comment: "corrects less English errors"  Corrects *fewer* English errors!

Comment: @Alex touche :-P

Comment: @CodyGray What do you mean "now that we have [...]."  Both options have existed for as long as suggested edits have existed.   You've always been able to edit a post with a pending edit, either rejecting or accepting the original suggestion in the process.

Comment: @servy No, I don't think so... I distinctly remember suggested edits originally supporting only "Approve", "Reject", and "Improve". Clicking "Improve" implicitly approved the edit, while allowing you to make additional tweaks. There was no way to improve while rejecting the originally suggested edit. I'm too busy at the moment to go digging back on Meta SE to verify this, but my recollection of it is pretty clear. I was involved in several discussions advocating for the feature. What can I say, I like to reject suggested edits.

Comment: @CodyGray When editing a suggested edit there was a checkbox indicating whether or not the edit should be approved or not.  You could do both, there just weren't separate buttons for it.

Comment: @servy Hmm, okay, you caught me at the right time. The "suggested edit was halpful" checkbox wasn't always there. [It was added in October of 2011](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/do-we-need-a-reject-and-improve-button), almost a year after suggested edits [were first introduced](http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/76284/1). Now, granted, 2011 is a pretty long time ago, so my comment was probably misleading in saying "*now* that we have". I just remembered the feature not always being there, and very much disliking it. I'd forgotten *when* it first showed up.

Answer (score 3):

> What should I do if this happens again?

A new, salvageable post with a lot of issues is likely to end up with both edit conflicts and an edit that misses some of the problems. I would say you should:

- Copy your version into something like Notepad so you don't lose them. Cindy mentions this in the comments and I've had success getting an edit applied on a 2nd attempt.
- If you don't want to wait to the subsequent edit to be applied, add a comment telling the OP how to fix their post. Be sure to include the `[edit]` link. Many new users don't know where it is.
- In the case of an OP rejecting improvements to their post, down vote.*
- If the post has something objectionable in it that you can't get edited out (either because of the OP rejecting or edit conflicts with edits that don't fix the issue), flag it.

*Clarification as requested in the comments:

The down vote arrow includes *it is not clear* as a reason to down vote. When a question has multiple comments stating that it's hard to understand and the OP rejects edits that fix spelling, grammar, and formatting issues, doesn't fix them themselves, and doesn't allow other users to fix them (sometimes even accompanied by comments yelling at *multiple other users* for trying to fix it), then yes, you should down vote.

This is not a "fit of rage". I do not care if the OP rejects my edits and does their own. I do not care if the OP rejects my edits and someone else's edit gets approved. I care that the question is hard to read or even understand and that the OP is going to make sure it *stays* unclear. The OP has essentially made their post unsalvageable.

You do not give up your privilege to vote on posts when you edit.

Comment: Suggested edits are never lost: one can see all of them by visiting all actions > suggestions in user profile. The source can be copied from there and reapplied. (It's a little tricky to copy the Markdown source from that page, since it uses a table for layout. But Firefox has Ctrl-drag to select a column of the table.)

Comment: `In the case of an OP rejecting improvements to their post, down vote.` ? This should not be done in a fit of rage of being rejected. The OP must have adopted a different way of explaining the problem. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Sandeep - It's not a  "fit of rage". See updated answer.

Comment: @Sandeep So wonderfully naive. Most cases (that I've personally seen) of OPs rejecting edits to their posts are because they object on principle to somebody else editing their post - indicating that they clearly don't know how the site works - rather than because they've themselves edited the post to explain it better than you had.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist  Naive? really !! Everybody has his/her point of view and if they don't agree with yours you call them naive. LOL.. What to do with experience if you can't respect your juniors.!

Comment: @AnthonyGrist true. I've myself had my edit rejected for fixing broken English and verbose title. Having said that, I don't think down vote is the correct thing to do. This will be impulsive; in most cases anyway.

Comment: *This will be impulsive; in most cases anyway.* @Sufian - If you cannot keep emotion out of it when you vote, you certainly don't have to, but it is a very simple thing to wait and see if either the OP or another user fixes the question. I thought my edit clarified that I never suggested that you down vote *immediately* or solely because your own edit was suggested. Do I need to edit my response again?

Comment: @BSMP my comment was in response to Anthony. I read your update now and I agree with you completely that a question should be down voted if the questioner is stubborn. +1