# Overlapping edits rejected by Community should be disputed

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Some of my suggested edits are rejected by Community due to overlapping edits.

> This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.

Is it possible to label it `Disputed` instead.

Labelling it `Disputed` would mean that the edit is valid but due to other reasons, it is not applied.

Labelling all overlapped edits `Rejected` would make a user seem to have many rejected edit suggestions, and also downgrade his credibility for edits.

Comment: Is it because one of the reviewers clicked 'reject and edit'? The only other edit happened ~35minutes after your proposal.

Comment: Rather than changing the label, we should just fix this loophole. See discussion in the comments [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318423/suggested-edits-being-rejected-due-to-worse-conflicting-edits). The problem is that a trusted user can force an edit through *on top of* an existing/pending suggested edit (in a couple of different ways). This loophole needs to be closed, such that the system always forces the editor to deal with a pending suggested edit. Especially now that you can "Improve" or "Reject and Edit," this is a low-friction change that reduces surprise.