# Loss of work when proposal is rejected due to conflict

Tags: bug, documentation, documentation-proposals

My problem is similar to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318423/suggested-edits-being-rejected-due-to-worse-conflicting-edits) question, but differs slightly.

I was working on a draft proposal for a few days. My edits (1) Moved all examples from the *Syntax* topic to a suggested new *Variables* topic, deleting the former, (2) added on to the existing examples from the former *Syntax* topic, and (3) moved/edited examples from a different topic into the suggested new *Variables* topic as supporting examples.

I saved this as a draft several times while working, and then when satisfied with the level of work I had done, submitted the proposal. After a day or so, I received a notification that my work was rejected due to a conflict: someone else had deleted the *Syntax* topic wholesale. (Incidentally, a *[Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/3059/variables)* topic has since been created, indicating that the deleted information is nonetheless relevant.)

Upon reviewing the rejected draft, I've found that I can neither move my suggested examples into the aforementioned *Variables* topic that has since been created, nor can I edit my failed draft in any way. I do not have any drafts listed on my dashboard. It appears, then, that the work that I (and others) have done on these examples has been lost.

Have I missed a button somewhere that will let me reuse my work, or is copy/paste my only recourse? Given that this does not credit others who have contributed, what should I do? Is this evidence that we need new features to handle this particular scenario?