# What causes this edit rejection: This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

What causes this kind of communication rejection :

> This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.

[image]

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Someone else edited the question already, and did so in a way that touches the same lines yours does.  Its a merge conflict, just like with source control systems.

Comment: thank you,but if there is an active suggested edit nobody can't suggest another edit,right?

Comment: @NiMa yeah, but. Anyone with 2k+ rep can edit the post directly. If he was editing while you have pushed your edit to review queue and then he submitted his edit yours was cancelled.

Comment: I had similar situation with one of my suggested edits - `This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit`. I prefer then the it should be `Cancelled` not `Reject`.

Comment: @TheCodingFrog Apparently these rejections [don't count](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277900/5321349) towards edit ban/warning, although they are still displayed in your edit stats.

Comment: @Cinnam  but nethertheless I get a warning that I should proceed with caution, because the last edit was rejected... ( same issue as OP )

Comment: Similar situation, and I edited it for maybe 8-10 full mins....

Comment: I know this is old, but rather than add a new question I just want a clarification. Does this 'rejected edit' effect your approved/rejected ratio? asked in a different way, does this increase your rejected edit number?

Comment: @JasonV No,not at all.It doesn't count as a rejected edit,because it rejected before even counting as a valid edit.