# Edit rejected but question is updated with my edit: This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

The rejected edit is from this question: [How do I save the text that the user enters into a UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30338350/2108547). I edited this question to improve its formatting, readability, tags, and changed some of the verbiage.

Shortly after, my edit was [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8128461). But now the question shows **exactly** what my edit suggested, minus the question title suggestion, and does not indicate that the question was edited whatsoever. Also, I'm now unable to find the original format of the question.

So what happened here? Did the OP see my edit, reject it, then copy and paste what I suggested? Why does the question not show that it has been edited? Why am I unable to find the original formatting of the question now?

Edit: [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286098/2108547) to a similar question suggests that if there are two edits that are alike the edits are then merged. If this is true, how does it know which edit is more *complete*? And wouldn't the question show that it was edited? Or is it because SO does not know who to attribute the merged edit to so it just doesn't show that the question was edited at all?

Comment: your suggestion is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8128461) I think. However it seems a lot less thorough than what you say.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier yes this shows my suggestion, but it also shows the original question *as* my suggestion. The original formatting of the question is no where to be found. It was substantially different before I suggested my edit.

Comment: It's possible that the OP sees your edit, copy it and edit his post accordingly, except for the title.

Comment: @nhahtdh Wouldn't the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30338350/how-do-i-save-the-text-that-the-user-enters-into-a-uitextview) show that it has been edited though?

Comment: @DanielStorm: There is a time frame of 23 seconds, though without knowing what was edited, I can't make an educated guess of whether the OP made the edit themself, or copied your edit and rejected it.

Comment: The original copy of the question probably didn't show up because the OP edited within the five-minute grace period.

Comment: voting to reopen as the duplicate was deleted.