# Edit conflicts should categorize as "cancelled" instead of "rejected"

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, suggested-edits

### The Situation

For those of us with <2k reputation, it can be tough to see your diligently submitted edit get rejected for this reason:

[image: rejected edit due merge conflict message]

> "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit."

The thing is, the edit wasn't really 'rejected'. It was actually just a [merge conflict.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286096/what-causes-this-edit-rejection-this-edit-conflicted-with-a-subsequent-edit) No big deal right? Except that it hurts your ***prized editorial statistics.***

### The Proposal

Change the merge conflict categorization from "rejected" to "cancelled".

Additionally, "cancelled" edits should not count against your (prized) edit statistics.

---

What does the community think?

*Note: I am only slightly biased as I did just get rejected in this manner, BUT if you look through the [merge conflict link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286096/what-causes-this-edit-rejection-this-edit-conflicted-with-a-subsequent-edit) there seems to be some traction for this idea in the comments section.*

Comment: Technically, rejected edits caused by a conflict don't count towards the edit ban but I do like the idea of calling it something different.

Comment: Second. Change this type to *cancel* is easier for editors to check their suggestions too.

Comment: @BSMP imo that's the perfect reason for why it should be reclassified.

Comment: Not "canceled" but "conflicted" can be better to understand.

Comment: Technically there is a review result called „invalidated“. This could be reused here.

Comment: @smileycreations15 I prefer "cancelled" - it's the end result. Similarly, "invalidated" works the same way. But "conflicted" is the state that would lead to cancellation or invalidation. I think it's more consistent to just give the end states - "approved" and "rejected" are end states already.

Comment: "Cancelled" with two "l"s? Hold on a minute chaps, since when did programmers start speaking the Queen's English?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm it's the only proper way to program. You start dropping the **u** from words, rearranging the **re** suffix and next thing you know you are dropping tea in the harbor. Which we all know just leads to bugs.

Comment: Does the "reject and edit" option generate the same reject-message? That would need to stay in place in my opinion, since if someone consciously chooses to reject a suggested edit and instead suggest an alternative, it *is* rejected.

Comment: Related question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290903/9614249

Comment: These are suggestions, suggestions get approved or rejected; they may be invalidated by something else. Suggestions aren't canceled nor completed.

Comment: I'm personally eagerly awaiting the status on this feature-request. I'm a "bad" editor, by my "editorial statistics". I do not wish to become a worse editor, so I stopped editing. I may start editing again, once I know I'm no longer a "bad" editor :)

Answer (score -9):

Based on our [current roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/28/the-loop-community-public-platform-roadmap-q1-2021/), this isn't work that we will take on, as it doesn't coincide with functional areas that we plan to improve in the near future. We recognize there is community support for this, but unfortunately, we can't prioritize it at this time.

Comment: That's very unfortunate in my opinion. But I assume the reasons must be that are already enough users willing to edit.

Comment: If you don't mind, what is being prioritized? Additionally, how hard would it be to implement from a developers standpoint? This is a pretty big problem which I actually encountered myself once, so that's why I'm asking.