# Force to review suggested edit before making a new one

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

In all of my edits, some are rejected because they conflict with others.

For example:

- [node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936 Error: Cannot find module '.yarn/releases/yarn-3.0.2.cjs'](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30158447)
- [How to display child routes in Angular on their own page for correct breadcrumb nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30006381)
- [Download Notepad++ with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29695306)

My edits are changing the title and the body. 2k+ rep users come and make approximately the same edit as me, rejecting my own.

All edits have at least 2h of late, so the suggestion was already sent when they start the edit.

To prevent this, I suggest to forcing people to review the awaiting edit before making a new one.

#### Why ?

- **Keep time of 2k+**: Don't have to edit manually. Just have to read the changes. And such as they already read the post (to think about make the edit) it will be faster.
- **Don't let 2k- have rejected edit** because it's bad for stats, for wanting edit post (cf bad_coder) and also because they take the time to do something that can be great.
- **The edit can only be better**: I see multiple time 2k+ rep people that just fix the code format or made quick edit to make the post readable. People like me will be reviewed, we (at least me) try to make very good edits, fixing all the details (I don't want to make people review 6 chars change). So, if they review edit, they will :

  1. Approve, and maybe add something else but the edit can already fix everything
  2. Reject, and so do what they would do if the edit wasn't present
- **Complete feedback of edit**: Actually, it's rejected as "Conflict". But: Was it a good edit? Will it be rejected or approved and why? All of those questions would get answers if the conflicter review edits.
- **Don't count as bad edit**. Actually, they are showed as "Rejected". Even if they are not include in [edit ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182983/284827), they are included in bad stats (that how I have 7 rejected edits). [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382519) is a related question about changing the name of this type of edit (to separate rejected/cancelled).

Comment: How is this even possible? If there is a pending edit, I as >2k user am always sent to the review queue before I can make my own edit. There may be an edge case when two users submit an edit to a post at roughly the same time, but a difference of 2 hours seems a lot.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is someone directly using the /edit URL if they have already reviewed 40 questions, but that shouldn't happen too often - it is not advertised by the UI, so few people should know that trick (and even then use it only on rare occasions where the pending edit is trivial/bad and one's own edit would fix all issues of a post).

Comment: Your edit went through 2 hours before the user edited it, so unless there's something wrong with the system, this is being forced.

Comment: This happened to the second suggested edits because somebody reviewed the post in another review queue, and chose to edit it - see [this Late answers review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/30006400). The reviewer likely didn't even know there was an edit pending.

Comment: Well see @WaiHaLee. But why it doesn't show my edit, or show "Pending edit" such as I see me ? It's strange. And are you sure that by typing the /edit you can bypass review ?

Comment: In review the posts are displayed differently. The reviewer wouldn't have changed the URL to /edit - they would have clicked a button that was available to them to edit the post to 'fix' it, from the perspective of the review queue that they were in. I should add that this is my conjecture - I'm not certain that this is what happened. As for whether you can bypass review by going straight to the /edit URL, the system will redirect to the pending suggested edit (I've tried this in the past).

Comment: Also, it is marked a 'rejected' edit, but it doesn't count against you - you won't, for instance, be blocked from suggesting edits if you have suggestions that are rejected because they conflicted with subsequent edits - it's as if you didn't do it.

Comment: See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182983/284827): "*We now ignore any suggested edits that were rejected by the Community User due to an edit conflict when determining whether someone should be banned from submitting suggested edits.*"

Comment: Oh, yeah, looks like the trick I described above has been [fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/363206/revisions) some months ago. The Late Answers queue may be an explanation. However, it would be weird if they didn't show that there was a pending edit. At least the Low Quality Answers queue takes you to the edit queue when reviewing as "Edit" while there is already a pending edit. Can't verify right now, but if that is the case then maybe a bug report may be appropriate (first check whether this has been reported already).

Comment: @WaiHaLee It may not count for blocking new edits, but the statistics of the editor will still show it as "rejected".

Comment: Related: [Edit conflicts should categorize as "cancelled" instead of "rejected"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382519/edit-conflicts-should-categorize-as-cancelled-instead-of-rejected)