# Why I am getting "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit" but there doesn't seem to be any merge conflict?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I have read the [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286096/4901118) about why this is shown and according to the answer:

> Someone else edited the question already, and did so in a way that touches the same lines yours does. Its a merge conflict, just like with source control systems.

but I can't understand why it is happening in this case when there is no conflict. I had modified the tags for the question and there was no subsequent edit which changed the tags.

Here is the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62385134/revisions) applied to the question.

Comment: You made an edit at [10:44:47 GMT](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26417171). OP made an edit at 15:09:17 GMT. Your edit wasn't fully reviewed before that edit, so it was registered as a conflict (and leads back to the question you initially linked)