# What should be the next step after I get "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit"?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I had asked a [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398350/4901118) which was about "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit".

I was told that OP made a change after my edit and my edit wasn't fully reviewed before that edit, so it was registered as a conflict.

I had modified the tags for the question and there was no subsequent edit which changed the tags. Also the modification in tags made by me was valid and was approved too. I think that the change was necessary and would have improved the question.

So what should have been my next step? Should I have done the edit again or left it as it is?

Comment: well, considering the question since got closed, taking action on that specific one is kinda pointless. (it'll roomba in 8 days)

Comment: Is this about making edits to that same closed question? Because you should generally not bother suggesting edits to closed questions unless those edits bring the question to a point where the question can be reopened. I doubt that changing the tags on the question will save that one...

Comment: If the question doesn't get closed then what should have been my next step? I understand that there is no point in taking action in closed question unless the question can be significantly improved.

Comment: If it's a useful edit, then yes, go ahead and suggest it again.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery That's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: "I understand that there is no point in taking action in closed question unless the question can be significantly improved" -- Thank you for understanding that, and not creating makework for higher-reputation reviewers (in both the Suggested Edits and Reopen Votes queues).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a few options, where the first might be less advisable if you don't have full edit privileges yet.

- Check the post again with the new edits and assess if your intended improvements are still substantial, then make the edit. That substantial part is important to get your edit accepted in the review queue or salvage a closed question.
- Ping ([@-mention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)) the user that made that edit and point out the issue you intended to make. Say something like *we were on it at the same time* to create some context.
- Leave a comment to indicate what can be improved.
- move on to another post that needs your editing skills.

Comment: I'd like to reiterate rene's point on "salvage a closed question" - if your edit does not make closed question eligible to be re-opened *please* do not make an edit as it likely take away OP's chance to get question re-opened.