# How to deal with people copy'ing your edit

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

I've had a weird situation where I improved a post a lot, there were over 20 grammatical mistakes that were all fixed. However, the person who asked the question did not accept my edit: Instead he copied it over and made his own edit, resulting in a negative edit suggestion in my account.

The question here is mainly, is there a way to remove this history from my account? I know it is not really a big problem, especially since the asker did not really did something wrong: He probably has no understanding of SO yet. But I'm trying to get as many edits approved, and this kinda makes me not want to edit these questions anymore.

In case you're wondering: I'm talking about the following edit:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28626514/revisions [Asker edit]
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7107069 [My edit]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their edit and yours *conflicted*. It was automatically rejected, and doesn't count against you. See [Edit ban because of Community rejections](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277893/edit-ban-because-of-community-rejections)

It looks to me like an honest mistake here; the OP tried to take your edit to heart and included the changes. They just didn't know how to approve your edit properly.

There isn't anything that needs to be done here; the edit got applied, the rejection doesn't affect your record.

Comment: I agree it was probably a mistake, as I pointed out in the question: However it does count towards another rejected suggested edit (which is ofcourse not a big deal, although it's still a bit awkward).

Comment: @KevinVoorn: but it doesn't count towards suggested-edit bans. Experienced reviewers know that the rejected count includes automatic rejections, there is no need to worry about that number.