# Asker approved edit, but Community rejected it

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

So, I recently [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15910844), and it was approved by the asker, but rejected by Community because it conflicted with a previous edit:
[image: Edit approved and rejected]

The post says that it was edited by the user, and it's got the edits I made (including the edit summary, a tag addition, but not a tag removal), plus an additional logcat that the user added to the post.

Can anyone tell me under what circumstances this would happen? If the community rejected it 1 minute before the asker, why was the asker able to approve it?

I don't think this is a duplicate of [Why did the Community user reject my suggested edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250129/why-did-the-community-user-reject-my-suggested-edit), but it is very similar. I could be wrong. In that question, the Community rejected the edit after the initial approval. In this case, the Community rejected the edit first, and then the asker approved the edit. Slightly different, unless someone tells me it is the same.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I think this _might_ be different than that, and I've edited the question to explain why. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @CacheStaheli It is the same thing.  The message even tells you now that your edit conflicted with another one.

Comment: Most likely this happened: OP started to edit, you suggested an edit, OP got a notification of your suggested edit, OP saved his edit (hence Community's rejection), OP handled your suggestion (approved), but since the suggested edit was already discarded, the approval had no effect.

Comment: Ah. Okay. That makes sense.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This is actually a bug: that edit shouldn't be approved.

[This morning, we released a feature to override suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178340/could-authors-overturn-recent-community-review-decisions/295028#295028). This is *only* enabled when there've been no subsequent edits to the post since the suggested edit was approved or rejected, as it'd be very likely to corrupt the post otherwise.

...But there's a bit of a bug in the check: it doesn't block the override action on suggestions that were rejected because another edit - one already in progress at the time the edit was suggested - was applied to the post. Such edits *automatically* reject the suggestion, without penalty to the editor, as (once again) they would likely cause corruption to the post if approved. The timestamp on the rejection is identical to the timestamp on the edit that triggered it...

...So what happened here goes as follows:

1. Bruce was already editing the post to add a bit of additional information (and format the code) when you submitted the edit to format the code.
2. You submitted your edit, which put it in the queue for review and also put a notification in Bruce's inbox informing him of the pending edit.
3. A few minutes later, Bruce finished his revisions and submitted them, automatically rejecting yours.
4. Bruce then checked his inbox, and clicked the link to view your suggested edit.
5. The system, failing to recognize that there'd been a subsequent edit, showed Bruce an "Approve" option on your edit, which he clicked and confirmed.
6. The system recorded Bruce's "approve" review, and then tried to apply the edit... and immediately failed (because there'd been a subsequent edit).
7. The system returned an error to Bruce, which read "" (nothing at all).
8. Bruce tried to approve the edit once more before giving up.
9. You found your edit both approved and rejected, and came here looking for answers.

Note that your edit was definitely *not* applied to the post; if it had been, it'd have wiped out Bruce's additions. Bruce did not make any grace-period edits to the question.

Marking this as a bug, as we should not have shown the override option in this situation. Thanks for bringing it to our attention!

Comment: There is pizza... on my screen...

Comment: I suspected as much! Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: _This_ is how you post-mortem to your users.

Comment: Imagine how good the SO edit system would be, if only one person could edit a post at a time. SO should just stop trying to be smart with this, the system is completely over-engineered. Mostly it leaves all users involved with edits confused, including the OP and reviewers. I have been around for quite some time (nearly 2k edits) and when there is a (minor) edit popping up during my (detailed) edit, I don't know what to do. I think it blocks my edit? That's from an experienced user - I can only imagine the amount of confusion that people who just got edit previligies have to go through.

Comment: And the edit system keeps changing. Often silently. As it did today, apparently.

Comment: Ever used a locking source control system with a large team, @lundin? Someone goes on vacation with files checked out and you gotta call an admin to break locks... It's ​horrible. We could handle collisions better here, but not without adding much more complexity... So instead we try to find rules that do the right thing in the common cases: privileged editor > unprivileged editor, large edit > small edit, etc.

Comment: Well here's a question, @Lundin : if only one user can edit at a time, should the author of the content be able to *take edit priority* over another user? i.e. Bruce posts, Angie starts editing, Bruce notice something needs to be fixed up and clicks "edit."  What happens?

Comment: Obviously there would have to be a time-out if someone is locking the post by editing, but not posting. 15 minutes seems reasonable. I don't think the OP needs to have edit priority, but perhaps a grace period from the time that the OP posts something, during which no one else can edit. With the current system, if I go in and fix spelling, title, tags, indention etc etc, quite a lot of changes - then the OP edits "btw this is for Linux kthxbai", then it can override my much more substantial edit. I haven't quite figured out how this works, but I know that it works poorly.

Comment: Typical scenario with current system. Bruce posts. Angie starts editing to fix problems. Bruce makes a minor edit. Then either he overrides the work done by Angie, after which she'll get pissed and stop working with quality improvements. Or Angie's work overrides Bruce edit, after which he'll get pissed and possibly gives up on the site if he's a new user. Or alternatively, the result is some mix between both edits, after which both users are confused and give up. Or the result doesn't make any sense. There is no possible good outcome, just bad ones.

Comment: As your multi-comment replies indicate, this is too complex an issue to be readily discussed in comments, particularly on a barely-related bug report @Lundin. If you wanna discuss this further, post a new question here.

Answer (score 7):

I've added a test to the suggested edit review overrides feature - if the suggested edit was rejected and the rejection has an identical timestamp to an edit on the post, I take that to mean the suggested edit was rejected due to an edit on the post.

In such cases, we do not allow overrides.

With you in the next build.